# Unable to mysql/mariaDB function through Laravel migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, stored-functions

I am trying to create a mysql stored function

```
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getDistance;
        
        DELIMITER $$
            CREATE FUNCTION `getDistance`(`lat1` VARCHAR(255), `lng1` VARCHAR(255), `lat2` VARCHAR(255), `lng2` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
            BEGIN
                DECLARE distance varchar(255);
           
                SELECT (6371 * acos(cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lng1) - radians(lng2)) + sin(radians(lat2)) * sin(radians(lat1)))) INTO distance;
                 
                if(distance is null) then
                    return null;
                else 
                    return distance;
                end if;
            END
        $$
        DELIMITER ;
```

if I execute the function through phpMyAdmin the works just fine and function is created in database

But when I am try to run the Laravel(v6.x) migration to create the stored function I am getting error

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStoredFunction extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       DB::unprepared('
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getDistance;
            
            DELIMITER $$
                CREATE FUNCTION `getDistance`(`lat1` VARCHAR(255), `lng1` VARCHAR(255), `lat2` VARCHAR(255), `lng2` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE distance varchar(255);
               
                    SELECT (6371 * acos(cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lng1) - radians(lng2)) + sin(radians(lat2)) * sin(radians(lat1)))) INTO distance;
                     
                    if(distance is null) then
                        return null;
                    else 
                        return distance;
                    end if;
                END
            $$
            DELIMITER ;
        ');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getDistance');
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
> CREATE FUNCTION `getDistance`(`lat1` VARCHAR(255), ' at line 1")

Comment: A little side note: `down` tries to drop a function called `distance`, but your function is called `getDistance`.

Comment: Double posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780770/unable-to-mysql-mariadb-function-through-laravel-migrations Remove one of the two

Comment: @brombeer, deleted 1 of 2, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELIMITER` is not a valid SQL statement. It's just a MySql client command. So just don't use it. The error you get tells you exactly that.

You can create a stored procedure in Laravel like this, this will render the `DELIMITER` obsolete

Try this

```
class CreateStoredFunction extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       DB::unprepared('
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getDistance;
            
            
                CREATE FUNCTION `getDistance`(`lat1` VARCHAR(255), `lng1` VARCHAR(255), `lat2` VARCHAR(255), `lng2` VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE distance varchar(255);
               
                    SELECT (6371 * acos(cos(radians(lat2)) * cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lng1) - radians(lng2)) + sin(radians(lat2)) * sin(radians(lat1)))) INTO distance;
                     
                    if(distance is null) then
                        return null;
                    else 
                        return distance;
                    end if;
                END
           
        ');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::unprepared('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getDistance');
    }
}
```

Comment: A good answer would include an explanation of what was changed and how it solves the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: The if / else construction makes no sense either. You can just as easily do `return distance;`